# normal() is always giving negative value

Tags: c++, normal-distribution

I am using `normal(mean, sigma)` to generate random number for normal distribution with mean and sigma. My sigma is 8db and mean is 0. But I always get negative value when I do normal(mean, sigma). Is there any way I can get positive number for this?

Comment: Did you write the `normal()` function? Is it coming from some library?

Comment: What library is this `normal` coming from?

Comment: I used example from here http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/cpp_src/normal/normal.html. I didn't include any library though and it worked.

Comment: Can you show us an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: @SadikshaGautam: There is no `normal` in `math.h`...

Comment: What compiler / OS are you using? I don't have a `normal()` in my `<math.h>`.

Comment: no normal in cmath, see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/

Comment: @user1: Don't use cplusplus.com as a reference; it's quite out of date.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth ok I didn't know that. Thanks!

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, really? It seems like I always end up there. What do you recommend instead?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: http://cppreference.com is substantially more up-to-date, IMHO.

Comment: Ok, I'm voting to close this.  Without knowing what library you're referring to, there's not much we can do to help.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Or rather, the OP just asked the question and disappeared.

Comment: I used the same method of the link I had posted earlier. I am pretty sure that this is not from math.h because when I remove the include "math.h", it doesn't give me any error. So, I am assuming that this is the built in method!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not simply call `normal(double mean, double sigma)`.
Instead, call `double r8_normal ( double a, double b, int &seed )`, where `a` is the mean, `b` is the sigma, and `seed` initializes the random number generator.

I was able to compile and use the Normal library in the [link](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/cpp_src/normal/normal.html) you provided.
I downloaded normal.cpp and normal.hpp. These are old files, mostly translations from Fortran.
I had to modify normal.hpp by adding `#include <complex>` and changing `complex` to `std::complex` in the first two declarations to get it to compile for me at low warning levels.

Then I created a test driver:

```
#include "normal.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int seed = 123;
    std::cout << r8_normal (0.0, 8.0, seed) << '\n'
              << r8_normal (0.0, 8.0, seed) << '\n'
              << r8_normal (0.0, 8.0, seed) << '\n'
              << r8_normal (0.0, 8.0, seed) << '\n'
              << r8_normal (0.0, 8.0, seed) << '\n';
}
```

which gives this output

```
8.19933
1.45505
-2.42428
26.9111
12.8398
```

And everything looks like it's working for me for mean = 0.0, sigma = 8.0.

Answer (score 2):

I only now read that you set mean to 0 and sigma to 8. I thought it was the other way round. So negative values are expected, not all the time though.

The random number generation is only pseudo random so if you only generate a few values and seed the generator with the same constant every time you might only experience negative values.

Try setting your seed using the current system time or generate a large number of random numbers to see if you really ONLY get negative values.